# Is it possible to avoid reloading when go back to previous page?

Tags: angular, components

I have a `HomeComponent` as below

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.loadAll();
    this.registerChangeInItems();
 }
```

`loadAll()` queries database via HomeService(I would not post the implementations here) to load all items.

In `ItemDetailComponent`:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

onGoBack() {
    this.location.back();
}
```

The first time the `HomeComponent` is loaded, it queries database, which is okay. Now the actions I do are:

```
1) HomePage -> ItemDetailPage
2) ItemDetailPage -> HomePage
```

In action2, it goes back to home page but reloads everything(queries database again). Does anyone know how can I avoid this?

Comment: When you call this.location.back();, URL should have been changed. You need to be able to manage your component state to decide whether it should call loadAll() or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want everything to be reloaded you need to place the `this.loadAll()` function somewhere else besides the `ngOnInit` function (which is called every time a component is created). This however probably doesn't make much sense.

Another solution that may work is to call the `ItemDetailPage` component inside of the `HomePage` component and only display the `ItemDetailPage` component depending on the condition of an `*ngIf`

In HomePage.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="some condition">
    <ItemDetailComponent></ItemDetailComponent>
</div>
```

This way the `HomePage` component is never ended and recreated.